# Laravel: First OR Update OR Create?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-9

I think I've talked myself in circles here.

I have a users table and a companies table.  They're joined in a many-to-many via a company_user table.

I can use `$user->companies()` to get all associated companies.

I can use `$user->companies()->first()` to get the first associated company.

What I would like to do is a: `$user->companies()->first()->updateOrCreate` type of method.

Where the goal would be: See if the user is associated with any companies. If so, update the first record. If there are no companies, create a new one and attach it.

I tried this:

```php
$company = $user->companies()->first()->updateOrCreate(
    [],
    ['name' => $validated['company_name']]
);

$user->companies()->syncWithoutDetaching([ 
    $company->id => ['relationship' => $user->type]
]);
```

And it works UNLESS there are no associated companies. Then, I, of course, get the `No first() on null` error.

Am I missing an easy method or do I need to create up some `if` statements?

Or, perhaps another option would be if `updateOrCreate` could search based on the relationship. Something like:

```php
$company = $user->companies()->updateOrCreate(
    ['relationship' = 'owner'],
    ['name' => $validated['company_name']]
);
```

Where 'relationship' is a column in the pivot table: `company_user`.

---

#### Update 1

I have tried:

```php
$company = $user->companies()->updateOrCreate(
    [],
    ['name' => $validated['name']
);
```

But it seems to grab the first company in the `companies` table.

Ignoring the fact that no relationship exists between user 2 and company 1. Company 1, in this instance, is tied to user 1. User 2 is not tied to any companies and, as such, I would want it to create a new company and attach the two entities.

Comment: For a `many-to-many`, you typically don't use `create()`, or `updateOrCreate()`, since both records need to exist for you to "Associate" them, and they should be able to exist independently (i.e. a `User` row can exist without an associated `Company`, and vice-versa). So trying to use `updateOrCreate()` on `$user->companies()` doesn't make a whole lotta sense, and `$user->companies()->first()->updateOrCreate()` makes even less sense...

Comment: Why not just `$company = Company::firstOrCreate(...)`, then `$user->companies()->syncWithoutDetaching(...);`? https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent#retrieving-or-creating-models. Or similar; basically, find or create the `Company`, then associate it with the `User` (unless already associated)